# kibana 4 gives an error "Discover: An error occurred with your request. Reset your inputs and try again"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

kibana 4 gives an error "Discover: An error occurred with your request. Reset your inputs and try again" 80% of the time when I try to sort by a numeric field. It works fine when sorted by any other field. Did anyone get this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had this when I had added a sequence number in logstash to index (because several logs could be added in the same millisecond, causing the sort not to show the ordering correctly).

If you open up firefox debugger and view the console, it will show you more information related to the error. In my case

**java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef**

I added

```
{ "unmapped_type": "number" }
```

into the advance settings - sort:options. It returns sorted data correctly but appears to throw a yellow warning.

Comment: Thanks. It resolved my issue too. Now, I am able to sort properly by setting unmapped type to number instead of Boolean (I had it set to Boolean before). I also see an yellow error that fetch from 5 of 35 shards failed.

Comment: I found out the error was due to some of the number fields not being populated, and in the end the only way I solved it was to re-index my data with the number always populated

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I had that issue and opening the browser's javascript console helped me to see that a non-JSON document was the problem. Apparently, you can store non-JSON in elasticsearch (at least I can with 1.6.2). That creates problems with Kibana.

[image]

So: Open the browser's console, look for "error parsing body" or smth similar. You should also get the faulty string. Use that to identify to culprit document.

[image]